# Flask url with only one parameter is not processed

Tags: python, flask, cython

My `sample.pyx` file contains

```
@app.route('/<lang_code>/')
def index(lang_code):
    return "language: " + lang_code
```

but when I navigate to http://127.0.0.1:5000/en/

I get a 500 error:

```
File "c:\code\flask\venv363\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: index() takes no keyword arguments
```

I've tried with 2 arguments and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `always_allow_keywords` option as suggested [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2136)

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name='main flask app',
    ext_modules=cythonize("sample00.pyx", compiler_directives={'always_allow_keywords': True}),
    zip_safe=False,
)
```