# Invisible keyword arguments in flask GET operation cause TypeError

Tags: python, flask

I have a very simple GET handler in flask that looks like this:

```
@app.route('/thing/<thing_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_thing(thing_id):
    """Get thing"""
    json_in = {
       "id": thing_id
    }
    return jsonify(app.thing_service.on_get_thing(json_in))
```

which is very simple, and complies with all the documentation for Flask. It works locally. However, when I push it to the server, it fails with the message:

`TypeError: get_thing() takes no keyword arguments`

which sounds like `get_thing` is being passed some extra argument, but only on the server. If I account for these mysterious extra arguments that should not exist, it works, but there appear to be no arguments:

```
@app.route('/thing/<thing_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_thing(thing_id, *args, **kwargs):
    """Get thing"""
    logger.info(f'args: {args}')
    logger.info(f'kwargs: {kwargs}')
    json_in = {
       "id": thing_id
    }
    return jsonify(app.thing_service.on_get_thing(json_in))
```

produces `args: ()` and `kwargs: {}` in the logs. But with this in place, the endpoint works. What could be causing this to happen?

The full traceback for the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File ".../python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: get_thing() takes no keyword arguments
```

Comment: Shouldn't `args` be a tuple `()`, not a dictionary `{}`?

Comment: You're right. It's a tuple. Fixed.

Comment: Please check if you have a base url set

Comment: Can you post the entire error traceback, so we can see where the call is made to `get_thing()`?

Comment: Added the full traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is found here: [Flask url with only one parameter is not processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66502303/flask-url-with-only-one-parameter-is-not-processed)

My code is cythonized as part of the CICD process. The local code is not. In the call to `cythonize`, the compiler directive `always_allow_keywords` must be set to `True`.